# How to solve a limit of a complex integral over part of the real axis?

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I solve:

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{|x|<1} {1 \over {x-i\epsilon}} dx$$

?

x is a real variable, and not complex.

Comment: this that $|x| = 1$ or $|x|<1$ ??

Comment: |x|<1, so over a part of the real axis

Comment: you probably mean $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{-1}^{1}  \frac{1}{x-i\epsilon} dx$

Comment: You have to be careful. The limit might not pull into the integral sign. In fact, if it does, the integral does not converge. So I doubt it does. Nevermind, I think you fixed it.

Comment: Try separating the real and imaginary parts of $\frac{1}{x - i\epsilon}$. The integral then separates into a real and imaginary part. You should be able to do the resulting integral.

Comment: ??
$$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \log \left(\frac{1-i\epsilon}{-1 -i\epsilon}\right) = \log (-1) = i \pi$$

Comment: But doesn't it matter if $\epsilon$ is positive or negative?

Comment: It does matter, @Neckutrek. You get a factor of $-1$ when you switch sign of $\epsilon$ and take the limit.

Comment: If $\epsilon$ is negative, that effects the branch of the logarithm chosen. Don't we get $-\pi i$ instead then? Sorry, I was assuming $\epsilon$ is positive in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think a branch of the logarithm is sufficient, $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x-i\epsilon} dx = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} Log(1-i\epsilon)-Log(-1-i\epsilon) $$
$$= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} ln|1-i\epsilon|-ln|-1-i\epsilon|+Arg(1-i\epsilon)-Arg(-1-i\epsilon)=0-0+0-(-\pi i)=\pi i.$$